# 'NCD.L1.sample--art-demo' command included `[number]` but returned 'unexpected number'

Tags: nearprotocol

The Repo is here: 
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--art-demo

I have set the environment variables as stated in the `README.md`

However as I tried calling the `design()` the following error occurred as shown:

[image: The Error]

Then I realised the contract might need to be deployed first, but there is no such command for deployment in `package.json`

[image: package.json]

Pls let me know how I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because the seed value you are using in the payload should be either a number without trailing zeroes or a string (wrapped with quotes). Notice the error is that the json parser is failing to convert the input to a json object. From the README I think it should be a number.

Try with:

`near call CONTRACT '{"seed": 1}' --accountId ACCOUNT`

---

FYI: This is going to fail, but with a different error. Both `CONTRACT` and `ACCOUNT` are invalid account names, so they won't be recognised. This tutorial doesn't contain steps for deploying, but as you pointed out, that is required before you are able to run it by yourself.